# Android: how to set app wide default font, with out overriding textAppearance

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-fonts

Im using custom font in my android app. I want to set this custom font to app default font (as fallback) but I still want to use the `TextView` `textAppearance` property to set font and text style.

It looks like setting `textViewStyle` or `fontFamily` in my app base theme, allays overrides `TextView` `textAppearance` style?

```
<style name="MyApp.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Overriding fontFamily also overrides textView textAppearance -->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans</item>

    <!-- Overriding textViewStyle also overrides textView textAppearance -->
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/DefaultTextAppearance</item>

</style>

 <style name="DefaultTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/open_sans_regular</item>
</style>

<style name="BoldTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/open_sans_extra_bold</item>
</style>


<!-- This textView does not get bold style -->
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Me happy"
  android:textAppearance="@style/BoldTextAppearance" />
```

Answer (score 14):

View's style attributes has more priority to textAppearance.

In both cases you have fontFamily inside style instead of textAppearance. When you put `fontFamily` directly inside base theme, view obtains that style from its activity.

So, instead of setting base `fontFamily` value in style, you need to set base TextView's textAppearance:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/DefaultTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="DefaultTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
</style>

<style name="LobsterTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/lobster</item>
</style>
```

So, here I have 2 textAppearances: `DefaultTextAppearance`, that is used as default for all TextViews and `LobsterTextAppearance`, that I use in specific case.

Layout looks like:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Default roboto text" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lobster text"
    android:textAppearance="@style/LobsterTextAppearance" />
```

So, first TextView uses fontFamily from base textAppearance, second one uses overridden `@style/LobsterTextAppearance`

[image: fontFamily textAppearance preview]

Comment: Lovely answer. The fact that Styles are higher priority that TextAppearance Attribute (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes#hierarchy) caused me issues, but this answer great as you essentially just set TextAppearance, nothing else, allowing the possibility of fine tuning TextAppearance. Well done.